# How to set ElementsByClassName() parameter with my a column coming from SQL

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql

I want to pass DAYSOLD Variable coming from selelect into java script  var daysOldCells = document.getElementsByClassName('DAYSOLD');

Look at the code below

```
(SELECT 
        (SELECT 'Company' AS th,
                 'Transaction Type' AS th,
                 'Project Full Name' AS th, 
                 'Prime Contract Number' AS th,
                 'Status' AS th ,
                 'Days Old' AS th
         FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS 'thead',
        (SELECT [Company] AS td,
                 [Transaction Type]  AS td,
                 [ProjectFullName] AS td,
                  [Prime Contract Number] AS td,
                  [Status] AS td,
                  [DAYSOLD] AS td
                
         FROM [ProProcessReporting].Engineering.[v_0901-Email-Server-notifications] [esb]
         WHERE [esb].[Receiver] <> 'Project Manager' AND [esb].[Receiver] <> 'Project Engineer'  AND [Status] <> 'Approved' AND [Status] <> 'Rejected' AND [esb].Email = @PAEmails 
         FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS 'tbody'
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('table')) +
N'</table>

 <script>
    // Add a script to dynamically set cell background color based on the  value
    var daysOldCells = document.getElementsByClassName('DAYSOLD');

    for (var i = 0; i < daysOldCells.length; i++) {
        var daysOldValue = parseInt(daysOldCells[i].textContent);

        // Adjust the condition based on your requirement
        if (daysOldValue > 2) {
            daysOldCells[i].classList.add('days-old-highlight');
        }
    }
</script>
```

I tried using select block on the

Comment: I have no idea what the HTML code resulting from that SQL statement will actually look like, so please show us that.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the class for cells directly in query without using JavaScript.

```
USE Nwind;
DECLARE @HTML AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @HTML=
(SELECT
    th='CategoryID','',
    th='CategoryName',''
FOR XML PATH('tr') , ROOT('thead'));

SET @HTML +=
(SELECT 
    td=[CategoryID],'',
    CASE 
    WHEN [CategoryID]<5 THEN
        (SELECT  'Class1' as [@class], (SELECT [CategoryName]) FOR XML PATH('td'), type)
    ELSE
        (SELECT  'Class2' as [@class], (SELECT [CategoryName]) FOR XML PATH('td'), type)
    END
FROM Categories
FOR XML PATH('tr') , ROOT('tbody'));

SET @HTML = '<table>' + @HTML + '</table>'
```

Raw output:

```
<table><thead><tr><th>CategoryID</th><th>CategoryName</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td class="Class1">Beverages</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td class="Class1">Condiments</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td class="Class1">Confections</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td class="Class1">Dairy Products</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td class="Class2">Grains/Cereals</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td class="Class2">Meat/Poultry</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td class="Class2">Produce</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td class="Class2">Seafood</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

HTML view:

```css
.Class1 {color:red;}
.Class2 {color:green;}

table,th,td {
    border:solid black 1px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CategoryID</th>
      <th>CategoryName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td class="Class1">Beverages</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td><td class="Class1">Condiments</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td><td class="Class1">Confections</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td><td class="Class1">Dairy Products</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td><td class="Class2">Grains/Cereals</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td><td class="Class2">Meat/Poultry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td><td class="Class2">Produce</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td><td class="Class2">Seafood</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```